# How to configure TightVNC to accept connections from localhost only

Tags: ssh, windows-7, ssh-tunnel

I just implemented tunneling [TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/) + [OpenSSH](http://www.openssh.com) for MS Windows successfully.

The last thing I have to configure is

> to deny any remote connections to TightVNC Server and allow local
>   connections from OpenSSH Server only.

Any clue how to do it? Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try selecting "Only allow loopback connections".  This requires a restart of the service.  It appears this does not apply to the web server that serves up the Java client.  I usually disable this service anyway.

Verify with the command `netstat -an | more` and checking which addresses are listening for port 5900.  If the change has been applied correctly, only `127.0.0.1` should be listening.

Comment: Hi! Have I use any IP filter in this case?

Comment: You shouldn't need one. However a deny filter of 0.0.0.0 239.255.255.255 would cover the full IP range.

Comment: Well... TightVNC is a bugged application. I did about 100 tests and IP filtering with Loopbacks is not working correctly.

Comment: @Dimi  You may need to restart after making the settings.  With the only loopback setting it should listen only on 127.0.0.1 preventing other devices from connecting.  That change usually requires a restart.